# Problems installing ArUco for OpenCV 3.1.0

Tags: macos, opencv, opengl, cmake, aruco

I already have installed openCV 3.1.0, and though some people have said otherwise, ArUco was not included in that.

I've been trying to install ArUco for my laptop (OSX 10.11.5), and I've downloaded the latest version of ArUco from the website, v2.0.7 (https://sourceforge.net/projects/aruco/files/).

I've unzipped it, created a directory build inside, and ran `cmake ..` from the build directory. My output looks like this:

```
-- GLUT_glut_LIBRARY=GLUT_glut_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-fopenmp=libomp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [ ]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
```

and has more tests for OpenMP and more failures.

At the end, it says

```
-- Could NOT find OpenMP (missing:  OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS)-- OpenCV_LIB_DIR=/usr/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib
```

How should I fix this? I have Xcode installed, and according to other questions/answers Xcode should come with OpenGL and GLUT.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing two libraries. OpenCV has its own implementation of aruco, nothing to do with that other project on SF..

It is implemented in `opencv_contrib` in a separate module named `aruco`: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d6a/group__aruco.html.

By default, contrib modules are optional, so you have to fetch both [`opencv`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv) and [`opencv_contrib`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) repos, and enable the modules you want during CMake configuration.

On OSX, I believe you can use Homebrew package manager to install OpenCV 3: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/blob/master/opencv3.rb.

Answer (score 0):

i think that aruco is made for windows and linux, not OSX. i know OSX and linux are both Unix but still, differences exist. thus you may not be able to build it on your osx machine. tell you if you have found a work around.